# ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary deprecated

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift4

Im using ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary to build an address but im having an issue because I tried using cnpostaladressformatter but got some errors. Can you show me how I would use cnpostaladressformatter to upgrade the code down below.

```
if let addressDic = placemark.addressDictionary {
        if let lines = addressDic["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [String] {
            return lines.joined(separator: " • ")
        } else {
            // fallback
            return ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(addressDic, true)
        }
    } else {
        return "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
    }
```

Comment: Seems to me that you'd have to create a CNPostalAddress object and populate it's properties (city, state, etc.) from your addressDic. Then you can use the "string(from" method on CNPostalAddressFormatter.

Comment: And fwiw, the CNContact framework was added in iOS 9 and is MUCH friendlier to use than the AB stuff.  This is why you are seeing deprecation warning(s) with the AB code you have.

Comment: @ghostatron can you show me how I can fix it, thats my problem, right now

Answer (score 2):

To use CNPostalAddressFormatter, you need to pass a CNPostalAddress.  To create a CNPostalAddress, you actually need to use CNMutablePostalAddress:

```
func printMiamiFL()
{
    let theAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
    theAddress.city = "Miami"
    theAddress.state = "FL"
    let formatter = CNPostalAddressFormatter()
    let addressString = formatter.string(from: theAddress)
    print(addressString)
}
```

So you need to create that address object, and populate it with the data from your dictionary, and then things should work fine.